# Syntax Error with ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myF, "sp.js");

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, js

I've a script referenced in List's view like :

```
<JSLink>~/retrieveAlarm.js</JSLink>
```

The first lines of the script show up an syntax error:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getAlarms, "sp.js");
)};
```

[image]

What I've made wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all add jquery reference properly and then try using `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAlarms);` and let me know this works or not.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Unfortunately does'nt works :s same error...

Comment: Then I think the problem is with your "$". check is there jquery file is loaded on your page or not?

Comment: Yes it's correctly loaded in the network tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to add jQuery reference also into the JSLINK.

Your path should be like

```
<JSLink>Path_To_jQuery|~/retrieveAlarm.js</JSLink>
```

Other than this, the syntax seems to be fine.

Comment: i added it in the jslink but still not working :s in the network tab i see the JQuery was correctly loaded

Comment: If I leave only ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getAlarms, "sp.js"); without $(document).ready()... it works well.

Comment: Yes, because we do not need jQuery for that. It is SP function. But you have used $(document).ready() that's why I proposed the answer. Great you solved!!!!